# About the intersection of any family of connected sets

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $(E,d)$ a metric space. We say that $E$ is a connected space if the only subsets which are both open and closed (clopen sets) are $E$ and the empty set. A subset of $E$ is connected if is a connected subspace of $E$. Let $\{C_i\}_{i\in I}$ a family of connected subsets of $E$. Is $$\bigcap_{i\in I} C_i$$ a connected subset of $E$?

Thanks for any boost.

Comment: Try intersecting a circle and a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Nice! :) :) :) :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Sorry, I should know by now to leave answers as answers, not as comments.]

Once more:

> Try intersecting a circle and a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the condition that every $C_{i}$ is compact, and the condition
that every finite intersection is connected, then the whole family
has connected intersection.