# Connectedness of set which is an intersection of some connected set

Tags: general-topology

Is a set which is an intersection of some connected set still connected? I think it is not true but could not think of an example.

Comment: intersection maybe?

Comment: Try to intersect two bananas.

Comment: Do you mean an intersection a collection of connected sets?  Draw pictures in the plane.

Comment: @ArthurFischer The thing escaped me, but you are right, I definitely should have. :-)

Comment: @JasperLoy An excellent movie.

Comment: @did You should make your comment into an answer.

Comment: @MattN. Done. $ $

Comment: At least contained in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/55646/8271)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to intersect two bananas.$ $

Answer (score -3):

I think that is true. Take an example in $\mathbb{R}$, 3 intervals [0,1],[$\frac{1}{2}$,$\frac{3}{2}$],[$\frac{5}{4}$,2], their intersection is [$\frac{1}{2}$,1] and [$\frac{5}{4}$,$\frac{3}{2}$] is separated